# Display dynamic content in Ember application template

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am creating an Ember app that manages a list projects and tasks for each project. In the app's navigation, I want to display the name of the selected project. If someone navigates to /projects/1/tasks, I want the page to display project 1's title, along with links to pages specific to that project. Here is what I have started for my `application.hbs` file of how I expected it to work, however the project title is blank and the links don't work:

```
<nav id="nav-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class='menu-project-title'>
      {{#link-to 'projects'}}{{project.title}}{{/link-to}}
    </li>

    <li class='menu-separator'>&nbsp;</li>

    <li>{{#link-to 'projects.tasks' project}}Tasks{{/link-to}}</li>
    <li>{{#link-to 'projects.people' project}}People{{/link-to}}</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container" id='main-outlet'>

  {{outlet}}

</div>
```

If I know every route will always have a `project` returned, what is the best way to pass that data into the application template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an Ember.computed.readOnly property in your application controller.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['project'],
  activeProject: Ember.computed.readOnly('controllers.project.model')  
  ...
});
```

But maybe this isn't the best solution. As far as I understand it, the project route/template is always used? So why not move everything to that template.

Comment: Putting it on the ApplicationController like that was the missing piece. Thanks.